# \maketitle has stopped working, despite backing up data

Tags: titles, microtype

Out of the blue I have started receiving the following errors (despite loading up previous versions of my files and/or bib. files from the cloud):

```
Runaway argument?
{\scantokens { \Huge {\bfseries {\@title }}
! Paragraph ended before \MT@prot@l was complete.
<to be read again>
\par
l.37 ...unter{tocdepth}{3} \parskip=0pt \maketitle
\begin{romanpages} \table...
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\MT@prot@group@@ ...er {\the \MT@toks \noexpand }}
}\endgroup
l.37 ...unter{tocdepth}{3} \parskip=0pt \maketitle
\begin{romanpages} \table...
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\MT@prot@group@@ ...r {\the \MT@toks \noexpand }}}
\endgroup
l.37 ...unter{tocdepth}{3} \parskip=0pt \maketitle
\begin{romanpages} \table...
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'
```

These errors coincide with line 37 which only contains `\maketitle`. My .tex file is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{oxfordthesis}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{chemgreek}
\usepackage{ghsystem}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
    \chemsetup{modules={all}}

\title{xyz} 
\author{xyz}           
\college{xyz}  
\degree{xyz}     
\degreedate{xyz}       

\begin{document} \baselineskip=18pt plus1pt \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} \setcounter{tocdepth}{3} \parskip=0pt

\maketitle 

\begin{romanpages} \tableofcontents \listoffigures \end{romanpages}}

\include{all chapters/bibliography etc}
 
\end{document}
```

**I'm really unsure where the error has come from, especially since I have loaded older versions of the entire document**

Comment: Remove microtype and try again.

Comment: see [here](https://github.com/schlcht/microtype/issues/3), and either use the code given in the link, or add `\microtypesetup{nopatch=item}` to the preamble (after `\usepackage{microtype}`).

Comment: Thanks both! That fixed it!

Comment: @robert can you post that as an answer?

Comment: Boy, you guys are FAST! I had JUST updated my LaTeX files (including `microtype` ) using TeX Live Utility, and BAM! had the error: `{\scantokens {\LARGE \@title  ! Paragraph ended before \MT@prot@l was complete`. Adding `\microtypesetup{nopatch=item}` WORKED! Are you telepathic or something? Thank You ... I could have spent DAYS tracking this error down! Thanks again!!!! Can someone post this as an answer so someone gets the credit? Thanks again!

Answer (score 8):

**EDIT:** This has been fixed in `microtype` v3.0b.

---

This <s>is</s> was a bug in `microtype`, which has also been reported [here](https://github.com/schlcht/microtype/issues/3).

A quick fix would be to load the package with the option `nopatch=item`, which will prevent `microtype` from patching the `\@item` command that fails here.

You could also disable the patching only temporarily for the problematic part of the document:

```
\microtypesetup{nopatch=item}
\maketitle
\microtypesetup{patch=item}
```

The real fix would be the following redefinitions, which will be included in the next update:

```
\makeatletter
\long\def\MT@prot@l#1{%
  \MT@get@prot{#1}{left}%
  \leavevmode
  #1}
\def\MT@prot@group#{\bgroup\afterassignment\MT@prot@get@firstchar\let\MT@temp= }
\makeatother
```